# Pulling a month of rows in SQL Server based on a dynamic day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table in SQL server that looks like this (there are other fields, but there are the only 2 I care about):

```
-----------------------------------------
|    DraftDay (int)|  MonthlyFee (money)|
-----------------------------------------
      1                 18.75
      2                 15.25
      2                 15.25
      3                 15.25
      3                 28.12
      4                 15.25
      4                  3.75
      4                 18.19
      5                 12.75
      6                 13.80
      6                 14.25
     ...                 ...
     ...                 ...
```

What I am trying to do is write a query that will group by `DraftDay` and sum the `MonthlyFee` field. Simple enough. But the hard part is, I need to get the date of one month ago, plus one day and pull the days from that day to the current day. For example, if today is 4/3/2014, then I need to pull all days between 3/4/2014 and 4/3/2014. My result set should look like this:

```
3/4/2014         37.19
3/5/2014         12.75
3/6/2014         28.05
 ...              ...
 ...              ...
4/1/2014         18.75
4/2/2014         30.50
4/3/2014         43.37
```

I have created this query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' +
    CAST(CASE WHEN EftDraftDay>28 THEN 28 ELSE EftDraftDay END AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' +
    CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS DATETIME) AS DraftDate,
    SUM(MonthlyPayment) AS MonthlyPayment FROM dbo.Advertiser
WHERE IsDeleted=0
    AND IsPaidInFull=0
    AND IsAdvertiserActive=1
    AND EftDraftDay>0
    AND (CAST(CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' +
    CAST(CASE WHEN EftDraftDay>28 THEN 28 ELSE EftDraftDay END AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' +
    CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS DATETIME)) >=
    CAST(CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' +
    CAST(DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' +
    CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS DATETIME)
GROUP BY 
    CAST(CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' +
    CAST(CASE WHEN EftDraftDay>28 THEN 28 ELSE EftDraftDay END AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' +
    CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS DATETIME)
```

Because today's date is 4/17/2014, I should be getting results back from 3/18/2014 thru 4/17/2014. The results I'm getting back are only from 3/18/2014 thru 3/28/2014. How can I also add 4/1/2014 thru 4/17/2014 into my result set? I thought about a `UNION`, but those don't seem to work well with `GROUP BY`'s.

After trying to figure this out and looking at my query, I think I am totally over engineering this. My query looks so complex for such a simple thing. Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: What's the relation between DraftDay column and an actual date?

Comment: @dean -- DraftDay is just the day part of the month

Comment: And how do you know if it represents a day in March or in April?

Comment: @dean - I'm using getdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @lastmonth date = convert(date,dateadd(day,1,dateadd(month,-1,getdate())))
declare @thismonth date = convert(date,getdate())

select 
case 
when draftday < datepart(day,@thismonth) 
then convert(date, cast(datepart(yyyy,@thismonth) as varchar) +    right('00'+cast(datepart(MM,@thismonth) as varchar),2) + right('00'+cast(cast(draftday as  varchar) as varchar),2))
else convert(date, cast(datepart(yyyy,@lastmonth) as varchar) + right('00'+cast(datepart(MM,@lastmonth) as varchar),2) + right('00'+cast(cast(draftday as varchar) as varchar),2))
end,
sum(monthlyfee) from tbl
group by draftday
```

This will treat days before current day as belonging to current month, and others as from last month, and then sum up. Please let me know if this is doing what you expect.

Comment: This code worked and it is definitely a lot simpler then my original query. Except I had to change it to `when draftday <= datepart(day,@thismonth)`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the Calendar table (http://www.dbdelta.com/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions/), something like this:

```
declare @d datetime ='20140403'

select c.CalendarDate, sum(#t.MonthlyFee)
from calendar c
left join #t on c.CalendarDay = #t.DraftDay
where CalendarDate between dateadd(month, -1, @d)+1 and @d
group by c.CalendarDate
```

Comment: A calendar table may be unnecessary, but that's a minor issue. A more serious one is that you are using `+1` to add one day. That works only with `datetime` and `smalldatetime` values, it won't work if the OP stores dates in a `date` column. `DATEADD(DAY, ...)` would be the only way to go.

Comment: Almost correct on +1 issue, but getdate() still returns datetime in 2008 :). OTOH, the calendar table is a must have (as well as numbers table)

Comment: Ah, indeed, you are only applying it to the variable, which you appropriately declared as `datetime`. Sorry, I should have been more cautious when commenting on things on Friday night.

Comment: I actualy highly value your spot-on comments, thanks.

Comment: Oh, that's really nice and reassuring to learn about, thank you too.